# Lodash update values between arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have got the two following array examples:

```
var a = [{ 
  id: 1560128,
  number: 'UNI01',
  state: 'PROGRESS',
  status: 1772627 
}];

var b = [ 
  { id: 92, description: 'In Studio'},
  { id: 93, description: 'Testing'},
  { id: 1772627, description: 'Active'}
];
```

I am wanting to create a new array or objects so that if status in array a matches with an id from array b, it will push the description value to the status key, and produce the following array:

```
var c = [{
  id: 1560128,
  number: 'UNI01',
  state: 'PROGRESS',
  status: 'Active'
}];
```

Is this possible with Lodash?

Comment: Are ```b```'s id's unique? If so, convert it to a hashmap.

Comment: not lodash but hope it helps https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPNRrV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lodash you can create a map of statuses by ids using [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy). Then [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) array `a` and get the description from the `statusMap` using [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get). Return a new object by using [`_.assign()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign):

```js
var a = [{ id: 1560128, number: 'UNI01', state: 'PROGRESS', status: 1772627 }];
var b = [{ id: 92, description: 'In Studio'}, { id: 93, description: 'Testing'}, { id: 1772627, description: 'Active'}];

var statusMap = _.keyBy(b, 'id'); // generate a map of statuses by id

var c = _.map(a, function(o) {
  // get the status from the statusMap, if it doesn't exist use the original status as default
  var status = _.get(statusMap, '[' + o.status + '].description', o.status);
 
  // create a new object with the new status 
  return _.assign({}, o, { status: status });
});

console.log(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

With ES6 you can the same thing using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const a = [{ id: 1560128, number: 'UNI01', state: 'PROGRESS', status: 1772627 }];
const b = [{ id: 92, description: 'In Studio'}, { id: 93, description: 'Testing'}, { id: 1772627, description: 'Active'}];

const statusMap = new Map(b.map(({ id, description }) => [id, description])); // generate a map of statuses by id

const c = a.map((o) => Object.assign({}, o, { 
  // get the status from the statusMap, if it doesn't exist use the original status as default
  status: statusMap.get(o.status) || o.status
}));

console.log(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do it with plain Javascript:

```
var a = [{
  id: 1560128,
  number: 'UNI01',
  state: 'PROGRESS',
  status: 1772627 
}];

var b = [
  { id: 92, description: 'In Studio'},
  { id: 93, description: 'Testing'},
  { id: 1772627, description: 'Active'}
];

var c = a.map(ae => {
  var be = b.find(be => be.id === ae.status);

  if (be) 
    return Object.assign({}, ae, { status: be.description });
  else
    return ae;
});
```

Comment: what I don't like about this is that you are mutating ae.

Comment: You are right. After you pointed that out I've come to the exact same code as you, just that I've first thought of using `lodash.merge` instead of `Object.assign`.